# On clicking at the submit, nothing happens. Have created extension.php in model and resource model and, collection,php inside Extension. Kindly help

Tags: database, modal-popup, submit-form

/*Submit.php*/

```
**<?php

namespace Eaglerocket\Customquote\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Eaglerocket\Customquote\Model\ExtensionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class Submit extends Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $extensionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        ExtensionFactory $extensionFactory
    )
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->extensionFactory = $extensionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        try {
            $data = (array)$this->getRequest()->getPost();
            if ($data) {
                $model = $this->extensionFactory->create();
                $model->setData($data)->save();
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__("Data Saved Successfully."));
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e, __("We can\'t submit your request, Please try again."));
        }
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
        return $resultRedirect;

    }
}**
```

/*addtocart.phtml*/

```
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = __('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php $buttonTitl = __('Get Quote'); ?>

<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()) :?>
<div class="box-tocart">
    <div class="fieldset">
        <?php if ($block->shouldRenderQuantity()) :?>
        <div class="field qty">
            <label class="label" for="qty"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="number"
                       name="qty"
                       id="qty"
                       min="0"
                       value="<?= $block->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>"
                       title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Qty')) ?>"
                       class="input-text qty"
                       data-validate="<?= $block->escapeHtml(json_encode($block->getQuantityValidators())) ?>"
                       />
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="actions">
            <button type="submit"
                    title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($buttonTitle) ?>"
                    class="action primary tocart"
                    id="product-addtocart-button" disabled>
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($buttonTitle) ?></span>
            </button>
            <?= $block->getChildHtml('', true) ?>
            <button type="submit"
                    title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($buttonTitl) ?>"
                    class="action primary" 
                     disabled>
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml($buttonTitl) ?></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



<a href="#" id="click-me">Get Quote</a>
<div id="popup-modal" style="display:none;">
    <form class="form" id="custom-form" method="post" 
    action="<?php echo $block->getBaseUrl().'customquote/index/submit'; ?>"  
autocomplete="off">
        <fieldset class="fieldset">

           <div class="field required">
               <label for="product_name" class="label"><span><?php echo __('Product Name') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text" name="product_name" 
                    id="product_name" value="<?php echo $_product->getName();?>" 
                    title="<?php echo __('Product Name') ?>" class="input-text" disabled>
                </div>
            </div>
<div class="field required">
               <label for="answer_name" class="label"><span><?php echo __('Answer Name') ?></span></label>
                <div class="control">
                  <textarea name="answer"></textarea>
                    <!-- <input type="text" name="product_name" 
                    id="product_name" value="<?php //echo $_product->getName();?>" 
                    title="<?php //echo __('Product Name') ?>" class="input-text" disabled> -->
                </div>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
        <div class="actions-toolbar">
            <div class="primary">
                <button type="submit" class="action submit primary" 
                title="<?php  echo __('Submit') ?>">
                <span><?php echo __('Submit') ?></span>
            </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>

<script>
    require(
    [
        'jquery',
        'Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal'
    ],
    function(
        $,
        modal
    ) {
        var options = {
            type: 'popup',
            responsive: true,
            innerScroll: true,
            title: 'Get Quote',
            buttons: [{
                text: $.mage.__('Continue'),
                class: '',
                click: function () {
                    this.closeModal();
                }
            }]
        };

        var popup = modal(options, $('#popup-modal'));
        $("#click-me").on('click',function(){ 
            $("#popup-modal").modal("openModal");
        });

    }
    );
</script>

<?php endif; ?>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#product_addtocart_form": {
            "Magento_Catalog/js/validate-product": {}
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You added form into form..
Addtocart.phtml is part of addtocart form..
Please place your form on anyother file.just button should here.

Hope this helps you

Comment: but for a pop up    modal it needs to be here and more over I need product details too

Comment: yeah I do have created and now its throwing the error Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in /var/www/demo/vendor/magento/framework/DataObject.php on line 191

Comment: check above link for reference

Comment: yes the same thing I needed for it

Comment: Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Illegal offset type in isset or empty in /var/www/demo/vendor/magento/framework/DataObject.php on line 191
how to solve this issue?

Comment: Commment your code and check it works or not and then debug it line by line

Comment: Resolved. You asked to create new file for the form but in that file <?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
 is not accessible and it was accessible in addtocart.phtml

Comment: Also I need to fetch questions from another table in my modal form.

Comment: <?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?> instead of this you can load current product registery that will also give you products data

Comment: https://magecomp.com/blog/get-current-product-magento-2/ I followed this for product registry and it is blocking the model pop up  and nothing is returning

Comment: something wrong in your code. please do compile and check once

Comment: how to compile only and not run it?

Comment: Run compile command php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: everyhting I am trying but not getting product details